# Force widget to update after returning to Launcher

Tags: android, widget

Is any simple way to force Android widget to update after returning to Launcher?

I just add some logs in override function (onUpdate, onEnabled, onReceive) but they are not showed :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is any simple way to force Android widget to update after returning to Launcher?

No, sorry. You are supposed to be keeping the app widget up to date as you go.